# Totaling Distinct Combinations Sharing a Value Via SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Very new to SQL, and here's what I have - basically a database of all players in each game of a season, like so (it's actually many thousands of rows):

```
Player   Points   Team   Date
Johnson  20       PHI    3-5-13
Jackson  30       PHI    3-5-13
Wilson   9        PHI    3-5-13
Anderson 18       DET    3-5-13
Thomas   17       DET    3-5-13
Coleman  21       CHI    3-6-13
Robinson 33       CHI    3-6-13
```

This is what I want to do with a query - list all two-man combinations for each team for each game and total them.  So, for the above example the two-man combinations for PHI for the 3-5-13 game are Johnson/Jackson, Johnson/Wilson, and Jackson/Wilson. So first it needs to get all possible 2-man combinations for all players on the same team on the same date. Then, I'd like a report that will total all those combinations across all games. So let's say Johnson & Jackson played in 25 total games on the PHI team, and Johnson & Wilson played in 13 - I'd want the final result to read:

```
Player 1    Player 2    Games
Jackson     Johnson     25
Johnson     Wilson      13
```

Any easy way to do this with an SQL query?  Basically I want to get all two-man combinations where they played on the same team on the same date, then get the total games for each of those.

Comment: What have you tried so far? For a start I would say you would have to create some sub queries and joins on those sub queries like `SELECT * FROM Players Player1 INNER JOIN Players Player2 ON Player1.Name <> Player2.Name` I may be wrong, but this is just a start.... You can also try making a fiddle here... http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Can you explain this part **Johnson & Jackson played in 25 total games on the PHI team**

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
select
  p1.player as player1,
  p2.player as player2,
  sum(p1.points + p2.points) as points,
  sum(1) as games
from
  games p1 join games p2 on 
    p1.player < p2.player and 
    p1.team = p2.team and
    p1.date = p2.date
group by
  p1.player,
  p2.player
```

The players are joined with greater than, so that you don't get the same combination twice (Johnson - Jackson + Jackson - Johnson).

Comment: i think this is doing the trick - thanks so much - i'll experiment a little more and see if anything isn't coming up like i want it.

Comment: actually a quick follow-up - how can i get the most recent occurrence (i.e. most current date and team) for each unique combination of players returned, in addition to the total points and count?

Comment: You can add team to group by and select, it doesn't change the results, and use max() for the date

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    [Player 1] = t1.Player,
    [Player 2] = t2.Player,
    Games = COUNT(*),
    Points = SUM(t1.Points + t2.Points),
    [Recent Game] = MAX(t1.date)
FROM Temp t1
INNER JOIN Temp t2
    ON t2.Player > t1.Player
    AND t2.Team = t1.Team
    AND t2.Date = t1.Date
GROUP BY t1.Player, t2.Player
```